# Matlab: Creating a blockwise permutation

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, permutation

I have a vector from 1 to 40 and want to shuffle it in such a way that each block of four integers (ten blocks in total) are shuffled only with themselves.

For example: 3 4 2 1 | 7 6 5 8 | 9 11 10 12 | ...

My original idea was to append ten permutation vectors to eachother and then add a 1 to 40 vector to the big permutation vector, but it didn't work at all as expected and was logically wrong.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: In the title you say you are using matlab but in the tags it says c++, which one are you using?

Comment: Clicked the wrong tag, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = 10:10:120;    % input: values to be permuted
group_size = 4;      % input: group size
D = reshape(data, group_size, []);                            % step 1
[~, ind] = sort(rand(size(D)), 1);                            % step 2
result = D(bsxfun(@plus, ind, (0:size(D,2)-1)*group_size));   % step 3
result = result(:).';                                         % step 4
```

Example result:

```
result =
    20    10    30    40    60    50    70    80   110   100   120    90
```

#### How it works

1. Reshape the data vector into a matrix `D`, such that each group is a column. This is done with [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).
2. Generate a matrix, `ind`, where each column contains the indices of a permutation of the corresponding column of `D`. This is done generating independent, uniform random values ([`rand`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)), sorting each column, and getting the indices of the sorting (second output of [`sort`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)).
3. Apply `ind` as column indices into `D`. This requires converting to linear indices, which can be done with [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (or with [`sub2ind`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), but that's usually slower).
4. Reshape back into a vector.

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much for the explanation as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `A = A(randperm(length(A)))` to shuffle an array.

Example in Octave:

```
for i = 1:4:40
  v(i:i+3) = v(i:i+3)(randperm(4));
end
```